# Debugging an app with Neo4j dependencies on meteor.com

Tags: meteor, neo4j, npm, graphenedb

I have create a Hello-->World Meteor demo app that uses Neo4j and [Dmitriy Aristarkhovich's Neo4j Reactivity](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/ostrio-Neo4jreactivity), with a hobby database running on [GrapheneDB.com](http://www.graphenedb.com/docs). The source is [available on GitHub.](https://github.com/blackslate/neo4jDemo/tree/master)

I have deployed the demo app to Meteor.com, where it is running in debug mode [here](http://neo4jdemo.meteor.com/). However, the deployed version fails to connect to the GrapheneDB database *.

When I run the app on http://localhost:3000, everything works fine. (That is, clicking on the button changes its title from "Hello" to "World" and back again). When I run it on Meteor.com, it shows "Not found" when you click, showing that no database connection was created.

What debugging techniques can I use to identify the cause of the problem?

---

EDIT: *It turns out to be a latency issue when the connection is first made over the Internet. If you wait a second or so, then all works well.

Comment: are you sure that you can connect to graphenedb using http? that would seem insecure. Are you sure the url isn't `https://..`?

Comment: All the URLs given at the [Connection Settings](https://app.graphenedb.com/dbs/Meteo4j/connection) page use the http protocol. So it looks as if http is the way it works.

Comment: Hello, I'm Alberto. One of the founders at GrapheneDB. @ChristianFritz HTTPS is supported on our production plans. Hobby plans ship with HTTP only for now. About the latency  issue: You might experience a few secs latency if the database has been inactive for a while because sandbox databases are stopped if inactive. Once Neo4j is running there should be no latency issues. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: @albertoperdomo When the page is refreshed, it can take a second or two before the connection is established, each time. I can refresh the page, wait a second and see that the connection has been made, and then all subsequent queries run quickly. If I then refresh the page and make query without waiting, then the query may fail. This is true even if another connection to the database is established, ensuring that the database is running. It seems that the 1-2 second delay is time it takes to establish the connection, not the time it takes for the database to restart.

Comment: Where is your app hosted? Usually the latency to establish a connection should be in the order of tens of ms, not seconds.

Comment: [http://neo4jDemo.meteor.com](http://neo4jDemo.meteor.com) Click on the Hello button immediately after a page refresh. If you see "world" (all in lower case) then the connection has not been established yet. As soon as  multiple clicks make the button toggle to "World" with an uppercase "W" and back to "Hello", then all is well.